# Django bulk create with using="" param

Tags: python, django, database

When I save objects using django model of save like this:

```
rank = Rank()
rank.save(using="test")
```

I would like to save bulk of ranks like this:

`Rank.objects.bulk_create(ranks)` -

how can I send to is also the `using` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`using()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#using) on the queryset:

```
Rank.objects.using('test').bulk_create(ranks)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood problem correctly you need to create [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for that and override bulk_create method inside of it.

```
class CompanyManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(self, self, objs, batch_size=None, **kwargs):        
        using = kwargs.get('using')
        if using:
            # your code here
```

now in Rank model you can specify CompanyManager as default:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    objects = CompanyManager()
```